# What is the fastest deterministic algorithm for incremental DAG reachability?

Tags: graph-theory, graph-algorithms, dynamic-algorithms

As the title. The incremental algorithm maintains the reachability information  of a DAG when it undergoes a series of edge insertions (but no deletions). And the algorithm supports constant query (if node u reaches node v) time.

It takes amortized O(n) time for each edge insertion (G.F. Italiano. Amortized efficiency of a path retrieval data structure. Theoretical Computer Science, 48(2–3):273–281, 1986.) on general directed graphs. Is it possible to do it faster on DAGs?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/q/14343/5038

Comment: Not a duplicate: the linked question is the same person asking about general directed graphs and that thread says nothing about DAGs. The second paragraph of the present question summarizes the answer to the first one.

Comment: Thanks for you comments. Yes, I asked three questions, for digraph, tree and DAG.

Comment: this might help: http://code-o-matic.blogspot.com/2010/07/graph-reachability-transitive-closures.html